# How to count number of unique values of a field in a pipe-delimited text file?

Tags: csv, unique, delimiter

I have a pipe-delimited csv file (can be made a .txt file if needed).  I want a list of all unique values in column 4.  I'm using a Mac with Terminal.  Thanks

Sample:

```
12345|1|2|Blue|54321
23456|1|2|Blue|23456
34567|1|2|Green|34567
```

I'd like a list that includes 'Blue','Green'

Comment: Please note the sample row above contains 3 records best arrayed vertically for this illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With macOS's built-in `awk` like this:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $4}' YourFile | sort | uniq
```

**Output**

```
Blue
Green
```

---

Your question title implies you expect the answer to be 2, because there are two unique values, in that case, count the lines too:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $4}' file | sort | uniq | wc -l
2
```

Comment: Mark, you are right my title was confusing but the info you supplied was great.  Thanks.

Comment: Worked with my Git Bash on windows too. Thanks